# Progress bar not changing state (color) when message box shown

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have a form with a custom StyledProgressBar. This StyledProgressBar simply adds a State parameter to set the color of the progress bar. Under normal circumstances, the progress bar acts as expected, but if the progress bar's style was Marquee, Value = Minimum = 0, and Maximum = 1 and I run the following code

```cs
progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
progressBar.Value = progressBar.Maximum;
progressBar.State = ProgressBarState.Error;
MessageBox.Show(this, "An error occurred", "Program", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Then the progress bar's color remains green rather than turning red. If I break my program before MessageBox.Show is called or, instead of breaking, put a `Thread.Sleep(1000);`, then the progress bar's color changes to red as expected.

Why does showing the message box block the progress bar from changing color, even after the message box is closed? Is there something I can do (besides adding a sleep, which is not a proper fix) to make sure the progress bar changes state?

For reference, here is the code for the StyledProgressBar class:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
    [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(ProgressBar))]
    public class StyledProgressBar : ProgressBar
    {
        private const int PBM_SETSTATE = 0x410;
        private ProgressBarState m_State = ProgressBarState.Normal;

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the color in which progress should be indicated on the progress
        //     bar.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     One of the System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarState values. The default is System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarState.Normal
        //
        // Exceptions:
        //   T:System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException:
        //     The value is not a member of the System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarState enumeration.
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(ProgressBarState.Normal)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Description("This property allows the user to set the state of the ProgressBar."), Category("Behavior")]
        public ProgressBarState State
        {
            get { return m_State; }
            set
            {
                switch (value)
                {
                    case ProgressBarState.Normal:
                    case ProgressBarState.Error:
                    case ProgressBarState.Paused:
                        m_State = value;
                        OnStateChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("The value is not a member of the System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarState enumeration.");
                }
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            // set the progress bar state (Normal, Error, Paused)
            if (Style != ProgressBarStyle.Marquee) SendMessage(Handle, PBM_SETSTATE, (int)m_State, 0);
        }

        protected override void OnStyleChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStyleChanged(e);

            // set the progress bar state (Normal, Error, Paused)
            if (Style != ProgressBarStyle.Marquee) SendMessage(Handle, PBM_SETSTATE, (int)m_State, 0);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        internal static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
    }

    public enum ProgressBarState
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates normal progress
        /// </summary>
        Normal = 1,

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates an error in the progress
        /// </summary>
        Error = 2,

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates paused progress
        /// </summary>
        Paused = 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I had `progressBar.Maximum = 1`. When I changed this to `progressBar.Maximum = 100`, the state changes to red as initially expected. Must be a bug in the underlying windows progress bar that status doesn't always update if Minimum = 0 and Maximum = 1.

Comment: Try: `progressBar.Refresh();` just before showing the MessageBox....

Comment: @JQSOFT, `progressBar.Refresh();` does not work. From trial and error, I found if max < 5 then the progress bar does not update, but if max >= 5 then the bar turns red as it is supposed to. I rewrote my code so if max < 5 it multiplies max and current by 8 before setting progress bar (with min fixed at 0) to make sure max >= 5 at all times. I've been testing on Windows 7 SP1, not sure if this behaves differently on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

before the MessageBox will solve the problem. Please see evidence of this below.

[image]

[image]

Is there anything else about your program or environment you wish to share?

Comment: I entered your code, single stepped, and Application.DoEvents() absolutely turns the progress bar red. Are you sure you're posting the same code you're running?

Comment: As mentioned in my initial question, stepping through the code does not yield the error (similar to breaking the code after setting state to error). It only occurs when I run the code normally. One additional thing that I learned (and stated in comments above) was it seems to be bug in the underlying progressbar. I had progressBar.Maximum = 1 in my test program in which the issue occured. I found that the issue occurs for any max value less than 5 (I did not try changing min from 0).

Comment: That is all the code I have in my test program. I created a form with a StyledProgressBar named progressBar with progressBar.Maximum = 1; and a button with a click event given the code in the question, just as it appears you have done. On my Windows 7 SP1 computer, I run the test program, click the button, and the progress bar fills green rather than red. If I change progressBar.Maximum = 5; then it fills red as expected. I don't currently have access to another computer to see if this behavior is the same on another version of Windows. In any case, I thank you for the help.

Comment: After re-reading everything you wrote, it seems that you're saying that it's the Maximum value setting that causes the posted code to fail. If that's the case, I fail to understand what this issue is to force Maximum to have a value that works. Are you concerned about others consuming your control? If so, expose a public Maximum property that keeps the private value set to only those values you know will work. Otherwise, if it's just for your use, avoid using a Maximum value of 1 if you have determined that this value doesn't work as expected under Windows 7 (it works on my Windows 10 system).

Comment: Thanks @Jazimov. In my main program - where max depends on the task size - I rewrote my code to multiply given current and max by 8 if given max < 5 so this issue does not occur. It's good to know this issue does not occur on Windows 10.